# I want to display an error message when an email address exists in a Vuetiify form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

## assumption

I am creating a user registration form using Vuetify. I want to display an error if an email address already exists at registration, how can I implement this functionality using Vuetify's `textfield`?
The configuration is loading the email componentized in the Form. It uses v-model between components with setter and getter to be updated reactively.

## What we want to achieve

I want to use `v-text-field`  of `Vuetify` to show an error if the email address already exists.

## Code

**Email**

UserFormTextFieldEmail

```js
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-col cols="12" md="10" sm="10">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="setEmail"
        type="text"
        label="email"
        prepend-icon="mdi-email"
        :rules="rules"
      />
      <p class="caption mb-0" />
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['email'],

  data () {
    return {
      rules: [
        v => !!v || '',
        v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || ''
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    setEmail: {
      get () { return this.email },
      set (newVal) { return this.$emit('update:email', newVal) }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Form**

```js
  <v-card class="pa-7 ma-10 mx-auto" max-width="600">
      <div class="login-logo">
        <img
          :src="logoImg"
          width="70px"
        >
      </div>
      <v-form
        ref="form"
        v-model="isValid"
      >
        <v-container>
          <UserFormTextFieldUserName :name.sync="userInfo.name" />
          <UserFormTextFieldEmail :email.sync="userInfo.email" :error.sync="errorMessage" /> // email
          <UserFormTextFieldPassword :password.sync="userInfo.password" />
          <v-row justify="center">
            <v-col cols="12" md="10" sm="10">
              <v-btn
                :disabled="!isValid || loading"
                :loading="loading"
                block
                class="white--text"
                color="deep-purple lighten-1"
                @click="signup"
              >
                ・・・
              </v-btn>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-form>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import '@/assets/css/user-form.scss'
import logoImg from '~/assets/images/login_logo.png'
export default {
  auth: false,
  data () {
    return {
      isValid: false,
      loading: false,
      logoImg,
      show: false,
      userInfo: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      errorMessage:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signup () {
      this.$axios.post('/api/v1/auth', this.userInfo)
      .then((response) => {
        this.$store.commit('alertSwitchSuccess', true)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$store.commit('alertSwitchSuccess', false)
          this.$router.replace(`/user/login`)
        }, 2000)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, what is not working here?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing before, and here's my solution:

```
methods: {
    checkemail() {
      axios
        .get("/api/v1/auth")
        .then((response) => {
          this.emails = response.data.map((a) => 
          a.email);
        });
    },
},
```

This function return an Array of all the emails

```
  data() {
    return {
      //email input v-model
      email: "",
      //declare the emails array
      emails: [],
      rules: [
        // your rules
        (v) =>
          (v && this.emails.indexOf(this.email)<0)||
          "this email is already existing",
      ],
```

I hope that helps